# why pageObject based on Cheezy does not work?

Tags: page-object-gem

I'm new to ruby (1.9.3)

I have intermediate experience with Selenium WebDriver plus C#. I want to move to Watir-Webdriver.

I'd be grateful to find out why the first block of IRB code works, but the second block simply loads the correct page, then does nothing. The page is active and responds to manual input.

The second block of code is based on the PageObject example here:
https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Get-me-started-right-now%21

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'http://x.com/'
browser.select_list(:id, "ddlInterestType").select("Deferred")
browser.select_list(:id, "ddlCompanyName").select("XYZ")
browser.button(:value,"Enter Transactions").click
```

Second block

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto "http://x.com/"
deferredPage = DeferredPage.new(browser)
deferredPage.interestType.select = 'Deferred'
deferredPage.company.select = 'XYZ'
deferredPage.enterTransactions
class DeferredPage
  include PageObject
  select_list(:interestType, :id => 'ddlInterestType')
  select_list(:company, :id => 'ddlCompanyName')  
  button(:enterTransactions, :id => 'btnEnterTransactions')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your page-object code example, after loading the page, an exception is likely being thrown (which makes it seem like nothing happens). That code should throw an no method exception:

```
undefined method `select=' for "stuff":String
```

When you declare a select list there are three methods created:

- `your_select=` - this is for setting the select list
- `your_select` - this is for getting the select list value
- `your_select_element` - this is for getting the page-object gem element

When you do `deferredPage.interestType`, it returns a string that is the value of the select list. Strings do not have a `select=` method, which is why you get the exception (and does nothing).

The two selections should be done without the `.select`:

```
deferredPage.interestType = 'Deferred'
deferredPage.company = 'XYZ'
```

As you can see the page-object API is slightly different than the watir API.

Comment: I resubmitted exactly as before, but with the two lines edited as you suggested. I get 30 warnings and the error      :5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant DeferredPage (NameError)

Comment: The comments about not using .select are correct. Plus, you defined your class after you used it...

Answer (score 1):

While googling for info on page objects, I found this page by Alister Scott. :

http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/04/roll-your-own-page-objects/

For an idiot++ such as me, I think I'll use his method until I know more about Watir-Webdriver. Based on @justinko's comment, I'll stick to one API for the present. I tried rolling my own, and it works fine:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie

class DeferredPage
  def initialize( browser )
    @browser = browser
  end

  def enterIntType(intType)
    @browser.select_list(:id, "ddlInterestType").select(intType)
  end

  def clickEnter()
    @browser.button(:value,"Enter Transactions").click
  end
end

dp = DeferredPage.new(browser)

browser.goto "http://x.com"

dp.enterIntType( "Deferred" )
dp.clickEnter
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let us know what error you are getting?  I suspect the problem you are seeing is related to the way the Ruby interpreter reads the code.  It reads the file from top to bottom and you are using the `DeferredPage` class before it is defined.  What would happen if you changed your code to this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

class DeferredPage 
  include PageObject
  select_list(:interestType, :id => 'ddlInterestType')
  select_list(:company, :id => 'ddlCompanyName')  
  button(:enterTransactions, :id => 'btnEnterTransactions')
end

deferredPage = DeferredPage.new(browser)
deferredPage.navigate_to "http://x.com/"
deferredPage.interestType = 'Deferred'
deferredPage.company = 'XYZ'
deferredPage.enterTransactions
```

In this case I am declaring the class prior to using it.

Another thing I might suggest is creating a higher level method to perform the data entry.  For example, you could change your code to this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

class DeferredPage 
  include PageObject

  select_list(:interestType, :id => 'ddlInterestType')
  select_list(:company, :id => 'ddlCompanyName')  
  button(:enterTransactions, :id => 'btnEnterTransactions')

  def do_something(interest, company)
    self.interestType = interest
    self.company = company
    enterTransactions
  end
end

deferredPage = DeferredPage.new(browser)
deferredPage.navigate_to "http://x.com/"
deferredPage.do_someting('Deferred', 'XYZ')
```

This is cleaner - the access to the page is abstracted behind a method that should add some business value.

-Cheezy

Comment: If I run the exact code from your first code block, I get the error C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- page-object (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
        from DeferredPage_Stack_01.rb:2:in `<main>'